# Can waitforbuttonpress be used with switch cases

Tags: matlab, switch-statement

I have used this piece of Code but it's not working. Can you help me where I am wrong here..

```
    for i=1:10
        keydown = waitforbuttonpress;
        switch keydown
            case'0'
                disp(5);
            case'1'
                disp(6);
        end
    end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are using `'0'` and `'1'`, when you should use `0` and `1`.
'0' - char type '0' (ASCII value of '0' equals 48. `double('0')` = 48).

`waitforbuttonpress` documentation:

> k = waitforbuttonpress blocks the caller's execution stream until the function detects that the user has clicked a mouse button or pressed a key while the figure window is active.  The figure that is current when you call the waitforbuttonpress function is the only area in which users can press a key or click a mouse button to resume program execution. The return argument, k, can have these values:
>
> 0 if it detects a mouse button click
> 1 if it detects a key press

Modify your code as follows:

```
for i=1:10
    keydown = waitforbuttonpress;
    switch keydown
        case 0
            disp(5);
        case 1
            disp(6);
    end
end
```